# How to prioritize firefox shortcuts over xfce key shortcuts

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, xfce, firefox

I would like to use the Firefox shortcuts for e.g. swap between tabs. But when I use CTRL+SHIFT+Pageup, then xfce will change window size. Is there any way to change the priority of shortcuts, so that when I am in Firefox, it will preferably use the Firefox shortcut and not the xfce shortcut?

I am using Linux Mint 19.3, xfce4.14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to fix this issue is to disable/unmap/change XFCE shortcuts. There's no "priority" to speak of - either XFCE intercepts them or not.